# AttributeError: module 'theano' has no attribute 'tests'

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, theano-cuda

I am trying to use theano gpu on my ubuntu, but each time after it running one time successfully, it will give me the error like this when I try to run next time. No idea why, could anyone help me ?

> > > import theano
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/home/sirius/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/**init**.py", line 95, in 
> > >           if hasattr(theano.tests, "TheanoNoseTester"):
> > >       AttributeError: module 'theano' has no attribute 'tests'

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem.I just fix it with `conda install nose`

Answer (score 0):

For latest version of Theano (1.04)

`import theano` generates an error without the nose package installed

install via conda or pip `pip install nose` / `conda install nose`